# How to skip password lock during the installation of certificate in Android

Tags: android, certificate, vpn, keyguard, screen-lock

I am installing certificate on my Android Phone programatically during which it asks me to set "screen lock". If its not there I have to explicitly go to Settings and set a screen lock which I understand is the Android firmware property for security reasons. But can I use below code to skip the lock? If YES then how ?

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. But you what you can do is, before installing certificate lock the device via
[Device Admin](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)
or if you have root access via db in /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases

But OS will force you to use some lock anyway if you will keep custom certificate. Unless you have a root access and forcibly clear the password. [Clearing passwords](http://en.miui.com/thread-5684-1-1.html)